# How to dispose user control with free memory when tab change in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, garbage-collection, infragistics

I am using infragistics TabGroupPane. In that case i am loding User control when ContentPane is active and remove previously active tab content.
here is my code Xaml :

```
<igDock:DocumentContentHost>
                <igDock:SplitPane>
                    <igDock:TabGroupPane x:Name="tabMainMenu" SelectionChanged="xamMainTab_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="False">
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="tabItem1"  Header="Item 1"></igDock:ContentPane>
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="tabItem2"  Header="Item 2"></igDock:ContentPane>
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="tabItem3"  Header="Item 3"></igDock:ContentPane>
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="tabItem4"  Header="Item 4"></igDock:ContentPane>
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="tabItem5"  Header="Item 5"></igDock:ContentPane>
                    </igDock:TabGroupPane>
                </igDock:SplitPane>
            </igDock:DocumentContentHost>
```

and code behide side

```
private void xamMainTab_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {             
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && null != e.RemovedItems[0] as ContentPane)
        {
            (e.RemovedItems[0] as ContentPane).Content = null;
        }
        GC.Collect();
        ContentPane selectedTab = this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem as ContentPane;         
        BindContainer(selectedTab.Name);
    }
private void BindContainer(string item)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "tabItem1":
                this.tabItem1.Content = new UserControls.UserControl1();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem1;
                break;
            case "tabItem2":
                this.tabItem2.Content = new UserControls.UserControl2();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem2;
                break;
            case "tabItem3":                    
        this.tabItem3.Content = new UserControls.UserControl3();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem3;
                break;
            case "tabItem4":
                this.tabItem4.Content = new UserControls.UserControl4();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem4;
                break;
            case "tabItem5":                    
                this.tabItem5.Content = new UserControls.UserControl5();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem5;
                break;
            default:
                this.tabItem1.Content = new UserControls.UserControl1();
                this.tabMainMenu.SelectedItem = this.tabItem1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

here i set content of last item to null.(e.RemovedItems[0] as ContentPane).Content = null;
but in that case memory(size) does not free.and then i use GC.Collect,this time some memory are free.
Is this write way to free memory or any other way then please provide me any reference of that.And also In this case when my user control contain WebBrowser then memory does not free if i use GC.collect please guide me on this also.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx can help you!

Comment: i read that article but not getting proper way.thanks for reply

Comment: @Gate What are you using to see if memory is freed?  Have you used a memory profiler such as SciTech Memory Profiler or RedGate Ants Memory Profiler to see if the instance of your UserControl is still referenced by something?  For the UserControl with the WebBrowser control, does the memory get freed if you also call Dispose on the WebBrowser control?

Comment: I use RedGate Ants Memory profiler,but not more aware of that.I look in to Task manager when i change tabs and again come back on first tab some memory like 2 to 3mb will increase every time. WebBrowser control will work fine now.